# how to show my current position(GPS ) in mapview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i was successful in getting the latitude and longitude of my current position from one of the tutorial.wat i want is to integerate this to my mapview so that i d get a blue indicator in my mapview.i know the basics of mapview in adding annotation but how to integerate my current location.i d be so greatful if u guys cud provide me an example.below is the code.

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SPEED: %f", [location speed]];
latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LATITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.latitude];
longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LONGITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.longitude];
altitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ALTITUDE: %f", [location altitude]];
NSLog(@"will dis :%d",location.coordinate.latitude);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting blue indicator showing user current position on map is really simple. Just set

`[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];`

on your ViewController containing MKMapView.

Also, it's useful to set the region of mapView nearby your current location. For more info, check [this Apple's example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746).

Comment: thanks Michal dat worked.i have tow query 1)i want a dialogue box  whether to allow my app use the currnet location 2)the gps area got to be 100 meters

Comment: 1)it's being shown automatically by the system. 2) play around with the sample code I mentioned above(esp. check method gotoLocation). Hints on how to calculate span you can find at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009734-CH1-SW29